# Java ArrayList Downcasting

Tags: java, oop, arraylist, downcast, upcasting

So I've been working in a project in which **I need to have a list to be filled with its new child class objects.**

I've made it with traditional method which **one ArrayList will be filled with a type of child Class.** But to make the code shorter and more efficient, I'm considering to downcast the ArrayList to have a single ArrayList of parent class that have both of it's child classes object inside it. Is it possible?

These are the parent class of Things

```
 package Model;

public class Things {
    protected String id;
    protected String name;
    protected double price;
    protected int stock;
    protected int bought;

public Things() {}

public Things(String id, String name, double price, int stock) {
    this.id = id;
    this.price = price;
    this.name = name;
    this.stock = stock;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public double getPrice() {
    return price;
}

public int getStock() {
    return stock;
}

public void minusStock(int bought) {
    this.stock = stock - bought;
 }
}
```

and these are its child class of Handphone and Vouchers

Handphone child class

```
package Model;

public class Handphone extends Things {
    private String color;

    public Handphone(String id, String name, double price, int stock, String color) {
        super(id, name, price, stock);
        this.color = color;
    }

    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }
}
```

Voucher child class

```
package Model;

public class Voucher extends Things {
    private double tax;

    public Voucher(String id, String name, double price, int stock, double tax) {
        super(id, name, price, stock);
        this.tax = tax;
    }

    public double getTax() {
        return tax;
    }

    public double getsellingPrice() {
        return (price + (price*tax));
    }
}
```

Thus to mention the main menu interface will be on different package, I put `import Model.*` on it. Will it also be included inside the menu package if I put it that way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put a `Handphone` and a `Voucher` into `List<Things>` (`Thing` would perhaps be a more appropriate name?), no need for casting:

```
List<Things> things = new ArrayList<>();
things.add(new Handphone("id", "name", 1, 1, "color"));
```

However, if you access the list and really need to know if it is a `Handphone` or a `Voucher`, you would have to downcast the object.

This type of casting could be sign of a design flaw, so carefully think your solution through.

Comment: What is the difference between List and ArrayList? What kind of design flaw which I might missed?

Comment: `List` is the interface. `ArrayList` is a type (probably the most common) of `List` which is internally backed by an array.

Comment: @DeanDebrio You haven't showed enough code, just three regular classes. I think this question is better kept as is though. You have https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ where you can ask questions on how to improve code.

Comment: Yea since my code isn't that complex, I haven't had any thought of reviewing it for an improvement in design. I just wanted to know because while casting an object is kind of 
extra work, why they make it in the first place at all if it cost a design flaws. Thanks for the recommendation though, I'll think about it.

Answer (score 0):

If you include a field with `protected` getter containing the class itself into your parent class, then it will be possible to know at runtime, was it a Headphone, a Voucher or a SomethingElse.

Make sure, though, as @Maglinex suggests, that you are not looking at a design flaw.

Comment: Was that means the casting process wasn't necessary at all if it's already inherited anyway?

Comment: Casting is still necessary, but the consumer of your List<Things> will know what to cast Things into by simply calling a getter method. Type erasure  is well explained here: https://www.baeldung.com/java-type-erasure

Comment: Could you please provide with that "protected getter" example? Looks like I need it to get specific object from the ArrayList